# Spring Cloud Config Server NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

when i build my spring cloud server local. I get this exception.

here is my sample project [spring-cloud-server-demo](https://github.com/tigerMoon/spCloud-config-server), just run with Application

I had test the git repository use the demo given by spring cloud [configserver](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver),it works fine.

this is my bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
    label: master
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/tigerMoon/spConfig-repo
          basedir: target/config
```

This is the stackTrace:

```
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:116) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:154) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepositoryPropertySourceLocator.locate(EnvironmentRepositoryPropertySourceLocator.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Please fix the url for spring-cloud-server-demo

Comment: @LipingHuang fxt it , thank you for pointing that

Comment: after one day，it`s going fine. maybe something wrong with my network.thank you.